# Animated UI Screen Resolution Unity

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I developed an android game with Unity, I used the UI System. I created a Loading Bar. A part of the loading bar is outside the canvas as its shown in this image [image]. I have a problem with it's anchors, when I want to put the anchors in the boundaries of (the black) loading bar, the anchors are limited and I can't move the anchors to the sprite, it stops in the red rectangle and what i want is to move the anchors to the screen rectangle as shown in the image.

The black bar is animated , so when i click on play the final animation of the loading bar is like this [image] and here is a capture of the UI canvas http://hpics.li/2054baa. what can I do to let the loading bar resize with the differents screen resolution.can I use the anchors outside the canvas? Can you help please. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

In both screenshots, you have the `Loading_Bar_Progress_Bkg` object selected, while what you should be concerned with is `Loading_Grp` object. Every game object in the UI hierarchy is configured relative to it's parent, and you if you want the *whole progress bar* (including both the common background, the loading cover and loading progress bar) to have a certain position, you have to work with their common root.